# one of haproxy backend server marked as down if the response time is over than 2000ms

Tags: timeout, backend, haproxy

my haproxy.cfg is :

```
global
    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4096
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon
    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
  option forwardfor
  log global
  option httplog
  log 127.0.0.1 local3
  option  dontlognull
  retries 3
  option redispatch
  timeout connect 5000ms
  timeout client  5000ms
  timeout server 5000ms


listen stats
    bind    *:9000
    mode    http
  ..................................
..............................................

backend testhosts
    mode http
    balance roundrobin 
    option tcplog
    option tcp-check
#    cookie SERVERID
    option httpchk HEAD /sabrix/scripts/menu-common.js
    server host1 11.11.11.11:9080 check cookie host1
    server host2 22.22.22.22:9080 check cookie host2
```

the log shows :

```
2020-08-19T16:02:14+08:00 localhost haproxy[22439]: Server Host2 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 2000ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
2020-08-19T16:02:14+08:00 localhost haproxy[22439]: Server Host2 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 2000ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
2020-08-19T16:02:18+08:00 localhost haproxy[12706]: Server Host2 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 2001ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
2020-08-19T16:02:19+08:00 localhost haproxy[12706]: Server Host2 is DOWN, reason: Layer7 timeout, check duration: 2000ms. 1 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
2020-08-19T16:02:27+08:00 localhost haproxy[12706]: Server Host2 is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 138ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
2020-08-19T16:02:30+08:00 localhost haproxy[22439]: Server Host2 is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 1ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
2020-08-19T16:02:30+08:00 localhost haproxy[22439]: Server Host2 is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 1ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.
2020-08-19T16:02:30+08:00 localhost haproxy[12706]: Server Host2 is UP, reason: Layer7 check passed, code: 200, info: "OK", check duration: 0ms. 2 active and 0 backup servers online. 0 sessions requeued, 0 total in queue.

at that time（ when the host is marked as down）， the call result will be 504 error rather than 200.

2020-08-19T20:16:02+08:00 localhost haproxy[3774]: 39898  22.22.22.22 504 POST /url/services
2020-08-19T20:16:02+08:00 localhost haproxy[3774]: 39909  11.11.11.11 200 POST /url/services
```

my question :
i have set the timeout to 5000ms, why the error was reported when the response time of backend server #2  is over 2000ms ?  can i increase the timeout to remove the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are looking for [timeout check](https://www.haproxy.com/documentation/hapee/latest/onepage/#4-timeout%20check)

> If "timeout check" is not set haproxy uses "inter" for complete check
> timeout (connect + read)

If left unspecified, `inter` defaults to 2000 ms.